# ProviderSetting Up Redux States (error: useMemo in Provider)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, npm, npm-install

I am quite new to redux, but am trying to set up state management as a way to reduce my API calls/increase speed. Since I have been stuck on this error for a few hours I tried to create a simplified version and am still getting stuck on it.

My simplified index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './globals/Redux/store';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);

const TestComponent = () => <div>Hello World!</div>;

root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <TestComponent />
  </Provider>
);
```

My store.js (which I know is working because I can print it out):

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import transactionsReducer from './transactionsSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    transactions: transactionsReducer
  },
});
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')

Full Output:
[image: Error Output]

Please help. I am a CS undergrad and working on my first major project and I think I am just making some small dumb error. Just to preface some debugging I have already done is try rm -rf my node modules and then rerun npm install aswell as verify react/react-dom versions match. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!!

Edit line 65 from Provider.tsx:
[image]

**Edit 2- I was able to get something new by rm -rf node_modules & package.json then resetting cache and redoing npm install, but now getting a huge error stack not sure if I moved up or down the error stack, but can't solve this now:**

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js 1:40-126
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /Users/joshbenson/Desktop/fw/frontend/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

ERROR in ./src/Assets/svg/Calendar.js 1:40-126
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /Users/joshbenson/Desktop/fw/frontend/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

ERROR in ./src/Assets/svg/Clock.js 1:40-126
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /Users/joshbenson/Desktop/fw/frontend/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

ERROR in ./src/Assets/svg/Credit.js 1:40-126
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /Users/joshbenson/Desktop/fw/frontend/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

ERROR in ./src/Assets/svg/Debit.js 1:40-126
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /Users/joshbenson/Desktop/fw/frontend/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

Edit- adding file tree:
[image]

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. This error continues for just about every file in the project. Thanks so much!

Comment: The error can be figured out by looking at the stack trace. It says you have an error in the `Provider.tsx` file at line number 65. Can you check what is wrong there?

Comment: Edited post to contain image of this

Comment: Regarding the `React.useMemo` issue, this just meant that React wasn't properly installed as a project dependency. After the edit though it looks like you have a lot of code trying to import from outside the `/src` directory. Make sure whatever you are importing exists ***within*** your project or is a global module (*unlikely*).

Comment: Hi @DrewReese thank you for your response. I added my file tree. I checked everything and think my node_modules is in the correct place. Becuase the error is in every file I hovered over the "import React from 'react';" and the full path was: module "/Users/joshbenson/Desktop/fw/frontend/node_modules/@types/react/index" Not sure if relevant, but still stuck on this

Comment: Look at the paths, they clearly start outside your project directory. What is `react-refresh`? All the errors appear to be related to *it*... can you [edit] to include your package.json file and the files using `react-refresh`?

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade "react-redux" package using `npm i react-redux`.

Comment: Tried this, same issue. I had already tried this previously in my debugging steps